# Get latest author posts inside the loop

Tags: posts, wp-query, author

I have a wordpress theme which needs to retrieve the latest 3 author posts which is simply straight forward but I have ran into a sticky problem.

Because I am calling this from already within the:

```
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) :the_post();
endwhile; endif;
```

For some reason it's not working.

Here is the code I have used:

```
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) :the_post();

//some content goes here regarding the post itself!!!
//some content goes here regarding the post itself!!!
//some content goes here regarding the post itself!!!
//some content goes here regarding the post itself!!!
//some content goes here regarding the post itself!!!
//some content goes here regarding the post itself!!!
//some content goes here regarding the post itself!!!
//some content goes here regarding the post itself!!!
//some content goes here regarding the post itself!!!

$relatedargs = array(

'author_name' => get_the_author(),
'post__not_in' => array( $post->ID),
'posts_per_page' => 3

);

$relatedquery = new WP_Query( $relatedargs );

while($relatedquery->have_posts()){ $relatedquery->the_post(); 

?>

<div class="span3">

<?php
if(has_post_thumbnail()) { 
$relatedthumbnail = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'medium', false);
$relatedthumbnail_large = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'full', false);
?>

<div class="hover_colour"><a href="<?php echo $relatedthumbnail_large['0']; ?>" rel="prettyPhoto"><img src="<?php echo $relatedthumbnail['0']; ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" /></a></div>

<?php } ?>

<h6><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><span><?php the_title(); ?></span></a><br><i class="icon-time muted"></i> <?php echo get_the_time('j') . '/' . get_the_time('m') . '/' . get_the_time('Y') . ' '; ?> <i class="icon-comments muted"></i> <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"> <?php comments_number(0 . __(' comments','textdomain'), 1 . __(' comment','textdomain'), '% ' . __('comments','textdomain')); ?></a></h6>

</div>

<?php } wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

endwhile; endif;
```

It works 100% on my local page but when I upload to the server it just does not show anything, I get no errors whatsoever, I'm on debug mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are executing `reset_postdata()` too early, using the global `$post` object incorrectly inside the secondary loop and passing wrong argumentes to the secondary loop. Try this.

Put the function to get the latest author posts in the functions.php file:

```
function the_latest_author_posts($post) {

        //some content goes here regarding the post itself!!!
        $relatedargs = array(

             'author' => $post->post_author,
             'post__not_in' => array( $post->ID),
             'posts_per_page' => 3

        );

        $relatedquery = new WP_Query( $relatedargs );

        while($relatedquery->have_posts()){
             $relatedquery->the_post(); 
             $ID = get_the_ID();
        ?>

             <div class="span3">

             <?php
                  if(has_post_thumbnail()) { 
                       $relatedthumbnail = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($ID), 'medium', false);
                       $relatedthumbnail_large = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($ID), 'full', false);
?>

                       <div class="hover_colour"><a href="<?php echo $relatedthumbnail_large['0']; ?>" rel="prettyPhoto"><img src="<?php echo $relatedthumbnail['0']; ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" /></a>
                       </div>

                 <?php } ?>

                       <h6><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><span><?php the_title(); ?></span></a><br><i class="icon-time muted"></i> <?php echo get_the_time('j') . '/' . get_the_time('m') . '/' . get_the_time('Y') . ' '; ?> <i class="icon-comments muted"></i> <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"> <?php comments_number(0 . __(' comments','textdomain'), 1 . __(' comment','textdomain'), '% ' . __('comments','textdomain')); ?></a></h6>

               </div>

    <?php }
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

Then, in your theme, inside the loop, you can call the function wherever you want to display latest posts from the author of the current post:

```
<?php
if ( have_posts() ) {
    while ( have_posts() ) {
        the_post();
        //some content goes here regarding the post itself!!!
        //some content goes here regarding the post itself!!!
        the_latest_author_posts($post);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Hi, It looks like it was because of the global post.

Thanks :)